# Is "could as well" a phrase? what does it mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I came a cross this sentence：

> *"But you could as well use part of your RAM for a partition. It's hard to guess this of every possible scenario."*

Is 'could as well' a phrase? Like 'might as well'?

Comment: Is there more info you could provide? It could mean *could also* or *could as easily*. For an AmE speaker, it's not a very well-written sentence, to be honest. It's a bit awkward.

Comment: No, but [***as well***](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/as+well) is.

Comment: @Catija The source is a forum thread, too long, can't post it here, I guess he means could also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the examples I found in COCA is from CSMonitor

> In another class, the instructor ***could as well*** be explaining how to start a new McDonald's franchise.

Even I come across such construction quite frequently. Remembering all those instances, I think, it does form a sentence meaning 'one *could also...*'.